# carplay-audio entitlement missing from provisioning profile

Tags: ios, code-signing-entitlements, carplay

Apple has enabled the CarPlay capability for our app, but when I download my provisioning profile I can't find the `com.apple.developer.carplay-audio` entitlement in it.

Here's what I did:

1. For our app identifier on Apple Developer Portal in "Additional Capabilities" I enabled **"CarPlay Audio App (CarPlay framework)"**.
2. After that I generated a provisioning profile and downloaded it. In the provisional profile info on Apple Developer Portal I can see **"CarPlay Audio App (CarPlay framework)**" in "Enabled Capabilities".
3. When I import the downloaded profile in Xcode, I can't see the CarPlay entitlement there. After I added the `com.apple.developer.carplay-audio` entitlement to my *.entitlements* file, I'm getting the "Provisioning profile ... doesn't include the com.apple.developer.carplay-audio entitlement.". When I'm opening the profile in my text editor, I also can't find "carplay-audio" there.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we had the same issue and that's actually Apple's fault on developer.apple.com. Go to your identifier and check the box on the "CarPlay Audio App (Media Player framework)" (NOT the CarPlay), hit save and recreate the provisioning profile. I remember contacting them and they told me the two options are mixed up :D

Comment: Yeah, indeed it looks like the options are mixed up, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@fruitcoder's comment works and that's an acceptable solution. fwiw once i enabled Media Player framework and made sure that it worked, i went back and enabled the CarPlay framework and it hasn't complained since. I believe the Media Player framework is technically deprecated and the new framework (iOS 14+) is the CarPlay framework. I don't think it hurts to have both enabled even if your app doesn't support iOS 13 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In the Additional Capabilities, there is only option"   com.apple.developer.carplay-driving-task". I hope renaming this in Runner.entitlements would resolve this issue. Thanks